# I need to change a belongs_to to a HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an article that belongs to a category

I have a category that has_many articles

I need to change this so that a category has many articles and an article has many categories.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a new migration for removing category id in articles table.Note: Data for all category Id would be lost

```
    remove_column :articles, :category_id
```

Another migration for HABTM references.

```
    def change
        create_table :categories_articles do |t|
        t.references :category, index: true, foreign_key: true
        t.references :articles, index: true, foreign_key: true
      end
    end
```

Now got to articles model and category model. REMOVE has_many relation and add HABTM as follows in both category and article model.

```
    #in articles model
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    #in categories model
    has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
```

Finally run

```
    rake db:migrate
```